# Jmeter warning sign meaning

Tags: javascript, apache, jmeter

I am running a stress test on server with Jmeter with

```
3000 threads (users)
30 second ramp up period
```

**Question:** Shouldn't the test finish in 30 seconds then? The test keeps going and I get something like (past 30 sec)

[image]

Something seems really wrong. What is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Something is definitely wrong:

1. Ramp-up period is the time slot when all threads (virtual users) will be **started**. So your current setting means that JMeter will add 100 users each second for 30 seconds. When thread is being kicked off it starts executing [samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to [logic controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers)). When thread doesn't have any more samplers to execute or loops to iterate it's being shut down. So your test will finish when the last thread (which will be kicked off after 30 seconds from the test start) will execute its **last sampler**, when it will happen - depends only on your test nature. If you want your test to last only for 30 seconds you either need to use "Duration" setting (lives under "Scheduler" section of the Thread Group)

   [image: Thread Group Scheduler Duration]

   or put your samplers under [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) and configure it to run for 30 seconds

   [image: Runtime Controller JMeter]

   Be aware that it might take some extra time to gracefully stop all the threads so your test can take longer than defined in the scheduler or the Runtime Controller.
2. A red number next to exclamation sign indicates that this number of unexpected error(s) have(has) occurred, you need to inspect *jmeter.log* file for details.
3. JMeter GUI is designed for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to running the load test (especially if it assumes 3000 virtual users) you need to [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui). Also make sure you're following recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide and [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

[ramp up period](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html) is about until when to start the threads, not when it ends. See warning in jneter.log or click on warning sign to find warning.